# Capitalize the first letter of the second word in a string

Tags: javascript

I have this code below:

```
if (e.model.item.name == 'billing account') {
const str = e.model.item.name;

this.$.id.entityname = str.toLowerCase() + str.charAt(8).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);   //str.join(" ")          

}
```

my goal is to Capitalize the first letter of the second element in this case `account` should be `Account` and then join the split string back together.

I have found the solution on the web for capitalizing every first letter of a string of text to uppercase. which is essentially looping over the string and using split etc.

Comment: And so what is the question if you have founded a solution ? provide exemple desired output and current output

Comment: `str.replace(/ \w/,l=>l.toUpperCase())`

Answer (score 3):

You can use split string into an array then trasform the first letter and merge it into new string like:

```js
const string = 'billing account';
let newArr = string.split(' ');
newArr[1] = newArr[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + newArr[1].slice(1);
console.log(newArr.join(' '));
```

Reference:

- [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)